# How to Update an "Array of Arrays", Convert it to CSV, and Download the File?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, export-to-csv

Forenote: I am extremely inexperienced with HTML and Javascript. Apologies for any part of the snippet that may seem inefficient or nonsensical.

In my application, the user inputs values to multiple textboxes, a bubble select, a dropdown menu, and a file upload in the form of a png image. Every time the submit button is pressed, I want these inputs saved into an array, and then that array is placed into another array, essentially creating an "array of arrays." An additional array is added each time the user submits their input. At any point, the user can request to download this continually updated "master array" containing all inputs submitted up to this point.

However, in my current code, whenever I download the CSV file, none of the previous submitted values are contained in the retrieved file. Essentially, an empty CSV is downloaded save for the default values that the array was initially declared with.

What I am wondering is, have I perhaps misunderstood a concept partway and created ineffectual code somewhere in my implementation. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

I initialized a global array called Log in Javascript with the first element of the array being another array containing the "Date", "Time", "Employee ID", etc. strings so that these default elements act as a sort of column header when converted to excel.

```js
<script>
    var log = [["Date ", "Time ", "Employee ID ", "Project Code ", "Task Number ", 
"Action Type ", "Chip Count ", "Chip ID String ", "Image "]];
</script>
```

Following the master array declaration, I implemented code to receive user input.

I then created a submit button that would save the current inputs by the user into a variable and place them into an array. This array will be one instance of a "log entry" and will be placed into a master array ("log") containing all log entries.

Date and Time are retrieved through the date constructor.

EmployeeID, ProjectCode, and Task Number is retrieved through input from a text box.

Action Type is retrieved through a bubble select input.

ChipCount is retrieved through a dropdown menu

ChipIDStrings are retrieved through multiple textboxes appended together into one string depending on if
the string is empty or not.

Container Image is retrieved by converting a PNG into base64 (I have a suspicion that any issues with code implementation may be pinpointed here).

```js
<!-- Submit Button -->
<button onclick="saveToLog()">Submit</button>
<script>
    function saveToLog() {

    // Preparing to Write to CSV File 

    // get date and set to variable 
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();


    // get time and set to variable 
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();


    // Set employee ID input to variable 
    var EmployeeID = document.getElementById("EmployeeID").value;

    //Set project code input to variable
    var ProjectCode = document.getElementById("ProjectCode").value;

    //Set task number input to variable
    var TaskNumber = document.getElementById("TaskNumber").value;


    // Set Action type to variable 
    var ActionType = document.getElementById("ActionType").value;


    // Create a variable that counts how many chips are being registered 
    var ChipCount = document.getElementById("elementreg").value;


    // Create a string containing all non blank chip IDs separated by a comma and space-->
    var ChipIDString = "";

    if (document.getElemendById("First Chip ID").value !== "") {
        var ChipIDString = ChipIDString + document.getElementById("First Chip ID").value + ", ";
    }

    if (document.getElemendById("Second Chip ID").value !== "") {
        var ChipIDString = ChipIDString + document.getElementById("Second Chip ID").value + ", ";
    } 

    if (document.getElemendById("Third Chip ID").value !== "") {
        var ChipIDString = ChipIDString + document.getElementById("Third Chip ID").value + ", ";
    }

    if (document.getElemendById("Fourth Chip ID").value !== "") {
        var ChipIDString = ChipIDString + document.getElementById("Fourth Chip ID").value + ", ";
    }


    // Create variable that converts picture to base64 string 
    var ContainerImage = document.getElementById("photo").toDataUrl();

    // Create an array containing all the variables and add it to the log array
    var logEntry = [date, time, EmployeeID, ActionType, ChipCount, ChipIDString, ContainerImage];
    log.push( logEntry );

    }
</script>
```

`

I then created a Download Button that would convert the master array into CSV formatting and download the file. However, when downloaded, nothing appears in the resulting CSV file save for the default string values.

```js
<script>
function downloadCSV() {
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + log.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n")

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

    link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
}
</script>
```

There was an option to use the Blob method to download the CSV file. However, some of my inputs such as the text boxes were required and did not allow the download button to be pressed without the inputs containing some arbitrary values that would never be submitted to begin with. I was unsure how to bypass this issue.